# Hp Dv6000 am i good to go

Tags: hardware, hp

I have a HP DV6000 and i'm interested in Ubuntu. I'm a noob when it comes to installing any firmwares on a computer, I just wanna double check before I begin.

My Computer Specs :

Model : HP DV6000

- Processor :Intel core duo CPU T2250 @ 1.73GHz
- Ram : 2038 MB
- System Type : 32 Bit
- Local Disk Space : 12.1 GB (NTFS)

It would be super helpful if you can recommended the version which works like a charm on my laptop. Also my dvd drive is broken I can't burn it into a disk, Can I install it with a USB or windows installer.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, there is a **LOT** of Versions on Ubuntu. It's hard to choose.

I would recommend Ubuntu 12.04. It's supported, quite nice, and you can install programmes to set your style more.

The easier ways to install 12.04:

[Stand-alone Installer:](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) Basically Wubi, but it doesn't dual-boot. Quite Easy.

[LiveCD:](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) Just follow the steps!

[USB Stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows): Again, follow the steps!

Hope this helps!